# Spinner ArrayAdapter using Resource from R.array

Tags: android, resources, spinner, android-arrayadapter

```
final String[] sortText = new String[]{"Date Uploaded", "File Name", "Up-loader", "File Size"};
Spinner sort = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.sort);
sort.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.sort_row_layout, R.id.sortTV, sortText));
```

The issue I'm having is that its unable to create constructor when I try to setup the adapter when pulling the array from resources so I can implement internationalization and have the text shown in different languages as so..

```
<resources>
    <array name="sort">
        <item>Date Uploaded</item>
        <item>File Name</item>
        <item>Up-loader</item>
        <item>File Size</item>
    </array>
</resources>

sort.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.sort_row_layout, R.id.sortTV, R.array.sort));
```

What could the issue be here?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter doesn't have a constructor you can pass a reference to an array resource to like that. See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

You want to use [`createFromResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) and [`setDropDownViewResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource(int)) like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sortAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.sort, R.layout.sortTV);
sortAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sort_row_layout);
sort.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
```

**EDIT**

For a standard, system default styled Spinner just use the built in layouts:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sortAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.sort, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
sortAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sort.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
```

Comment: I'm running into this problem now. It's wanting a layout instead of the TextView. Now how to set the addapter to set the text to this view?ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sortAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.sort, R.layout.sort_row_layout);

Comment: The Spinner wants a layout file with just a TextView in it and it will automatically put the values in your array into the Spinner as the options. Is there something custom you're trying to do by passing your own layout? I'm going to edit my answer above with an example of a system default styled Spinner using your array